# laravel csv will not import

Tags: php, laravel, csv, import-from-excel

I have import function to import data from csv file in my products table, I get successful result back but nothing imports to my database.

```
    public function import(Request $request) {
          //
          $this->validate($request,[
            'file' => 'required|mimes:csv,txt',
          ]);

          if(($handle = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"r")) !== FALSE) {
            fgetcsv($handle); //remove first row of excel file such as title

                  while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                          $product = new Product;
                          $product->title = $data[0];
                          $product->slug = $data[1];
                          $product->imageOne = $data[2];
                          $product->imageTwo = $data[3];
                          $product->short_description = $data[4];
                          $product->description = $data[5];
                          $product->price = $data[6];
                          $product->meta_description = $data[7];
                          $product->meta_tags = $data[8];
// Other fields...
                          $product->created_at = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                          $product->updated_at = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                          $product->save();
                  }
                  fclose($handle);
              }

          Session::flash('success', 'Your products imported successfully.');
          return redirect()->back();
        }
```

route

```
Route::post('import_products', 'ProductController@import')->name('import_products');
```

form

```
<form action="{{route('import_products')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              {{csrf_field()}}
              <div class="input-group">
                <input type="file" class="form-control" name="file">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                  <!-- Buttons -->
                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Upload</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
```

my table structure

[image]

any idea?

Comment: have you tried dd( $data ); just after the while ?

Comment: no, i try it....

Comment: @RezaSh nothing will dd, still returning my session::flash!

Comment: so $data is false , try commenting fgetcsv($handle); line and test again

Comment: @RezaSh return `false`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider to install this library.

http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/import

It works perfectly to my several projects.

```
Excel::load($request->file('file'), function($reader) {
            $results = $reader->all();

            $results->each(function($row) {
             //code to model here...
});
```

Comment: seems so complected package! I've seen that before but have no idea how to setting it.

Comment: i might able to help you

Comment: install this to your composer 

"maatwebsite/excel" : "~2.1.0"

Comment: include this to your providers in app.php in config folder Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class,

Comment: same file , add this to your aliases : 'Excel' => Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::class,

Comment: call this to your cmd php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider"

Comment: Now it's all setup. Use Excel to any of your Controller

Comment: i hope you'll able to understand each instruction

Comment: should i use `use xxxx` in top of my controler?

Comment: Yes inorder to invoke the class within the controller.

Comment: Undefined variable: data

Comment: $product->title = $data[0];

Comment: $results->each(function($row) {

//$row will be the variable to be used instead of $data

Comment: also . $row->column1 , $row->column2 to get the data

Comment: first row will be the column name

Comment: or try to call dd($result)

Comment: it gives me validation error while my fields are not null

Comment: are u required to use CSV ? or u  have option to use xls file ?

Comment: maybe is the best to have option to use both if it's possible?   Ps: https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/1548

Comment: yeah . regardless if its xls or csv file . but you need to double check the config file as well . i can share my setting

Comment: would be appreciated. really confused why it returns error while i have data!

Comment: hi, how r u? i'm still waiting for your respond.

Comment: Hello you want to have a remote later when i got to office.